# Mask 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following array as an image with three layers (red, green, blue). For each position in the image i want to test whether there is a specific value in one of the layers (e.g. 99). If that is true the values at the same position in the other layers shall be replaced by this specific value.

```
img = np.array([[[0, 99],
                 [2, 3]],
                     
                 [[4, 5],
                  [6, 7]],
                     
                 [[8, 9],
                  [10, 11]]])
```

The desired result would be:

```
img = [[[0, 99],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 99],
        [6, 7]],

       [[8, 99],
        [10, 11]]]
```

I am currently using the following code to fulfill the task.

```
c= []
for i in range(img.shape[1]):
    for j in range(img.shape[2]):
        if np.any(img[:, i, j]==99):
            c.append([99 for x in img[:, i, j]])
        else: c.append(img[:, i, j])

new_img = [np.array([row[i] for row in c]).reshape((2,2)).tolist() for i in range(len(c))]
```

However, this seems somewhat complicated. Can you recommend a better approach? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Sorry, didn't see your comment when I was posting.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Fair enough. I bothered answering because it's the first one I recall seeing where the masked axes are not the leading axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask of pixels that are 99 in any channel is

```
mask = (img == 99).any(0)
```

You can apply this mask directly:

```
img[:, mask] = 99
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
img[:, (img == 99).any(0)] = 99
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

```
ind = np.argwhere(img == 99)[0, 1:]   # [0, 1]
img[:, ind[0], ind[1]] = 99
# [[[ 0 99]
#   [ 2  3]]
#  [[ 4 99]
#   [ 6  7]]
#  [[ 8 99]
#   [10 11]]]
```

which will work just on the first occurrence of 99. So, if you have more than one layer contain 99 or more than one count of 99 in each layer, do as @Mad solution.